# Ошибка в решении задачи

Tags: c++

Вот задача:

> Составить программу, которая на входе должна получать
>   последовательность цифр, после чего  программа показывает цифру,
>   порядковый номер которой ввел пользователь.

И вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char string[100];
    cout << "Введите последовательность цифр: ";
    cin >> string;
    int k;
    cout << "\nВведите порядковый номер цифры: ";
    cin >> k;
    if ((k - 1) < 0 || k > strlen(string))
        cout << "\nНекорректный ввод порядкового номера" << endl << endl;
    else
    cout << "\nk-я цифра последовательности: " << string[k] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Однако он не работает. Где же ошибка?

Comment: Отладчик попробуйте...

Comment: Этот код [работает](https://ideone.com/foZvOq). Но не во всех случаях и, скорее всего, не совсем так, как вы ожидаете.

Comment: Вы бы еще в строках вывода `n` заменили на `\n`

Comment: вы вводите в массив символов  так  cin >> string;  ваш string это не std::string...

Comment: Я знаю, это char-массив...

Comment: ну а разве так можете инициализировать C_ массив ?...

Comment: Вроде работает... Хотя, пожалуй, стоит заменить на srting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуй, напишу еще один ответ. Так как данный вопрос помечен как относящийся к С++, то было бы лучше заменить массив *char'а* строкой string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string string;
    cout << "Введите последовательность цифр: ";
    getline (cin, string);
    int k;
    cout << "nВведите порядковый номер цифры: ";
    cin >> k;
    if ((k - 1) < 0 || k > string.length())
        cout << "nНекорректный ввод порядкового номера" << endl << endl;
    else
    cout << "nk-я цифра последовательности: " << string[k - 1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Важно! *Результат выполнения кода почти не изменится, только увеличится максимальная длина последовательности!* Если нужно его поставить, проинициализируйте переменную string должным образом.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в строке:

```
cout << "\nk-я цифра последовательности: " << string[k] << endl;
```

А надо:

```
cout << "\nk-я цифра последовательности: " << string[k - 1] << endl;
```

Дело в том, что в массивах счет индексов начинается с нуля. Попробуйте, должно заработать. Хотя странно, что ошибка именно в этом месте.

Comment: Не вижу ничего странного...

Comment: Даниил Чижевский, да это ошибка, но не из за этого не работает код, из за этого выдаст  просто неправильный ответ

Comment: Как неправильно написал ТС, *код работает.* Он выдает не тот результат, и все. Хотя с массивом char и наблюдается достаточно интересный эффект, в этом ответе я его убирать не буду.

Comment: @ Даниил Чижевский , если используете код автора ,  то у вас работает,  потому что вы вводите без символов разделителей, а попробуйте после первого же символа ставить пробел...

Comment: Тогда надо по-другому...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, вот, исправил. Теперь вместо вывода не НЕ ЦИФРЫ выводит соответствующую надпись: [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/dJi2Qp)

Comment: @Даниил Чижевский ,  а isNumber()? Я такую функцию не знаю, но без этого условия ваш код работает у меня.  А вместо  isNumber()  запишите isalpha()...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, посмотрите, протрите глаза - эта функция реализована прямо там ;) Это Bool-функция, самая простейшая.

Comment: @ Даниил Чижевский  Да, не заметил, ну тогда все нормально. С этой функцией ваш код у меня выдает правильный результат

Answer (score 0):

поменяйте способ ввода

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(string); ++i)
        std::cin >> string[i];
```

я думаю вы вводили цифры и где то ввели пробел, потому и не работал код,
а лучше вводить в std::string

Comment: 1. `i < strlen(string)` - не надо так делать - вызов strlen на кажой итерации существенно замедляет программу, надо сохпранять длину в переменную. 2. Что-то ввод вимволов стрроки, у которой ты замеряещь длину - это какой-то бред... 3. Как это вообще должно помочь-то?

Answer (score -1):

Ошибка здесь:

```
cout << "nk-я цифра последовательности: " << string[k] << endl;
```

Индекс измените на `[k - 1]`.